# text-indent on user formatted text

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to use the text-indent property (or something like this) to add a indentation of the first line of each paragraph.

First the user can write his text in a textarea, then save it in a DB.

When I want to display this text i use :

```
$exhib = $res->fetch_array();
echo "<div class='infoContent'>". nl2br($exhib['description']) . "</p></div>";
```

The line return of the user are stored as `\n` in DB, and modified to `<br />` by `nl2br`. With my CSS :

```
.infoContent
{
   text-indent: 10px;
}
```

only the first line is indented. (normal behavior).

**Q** : How can I make this indentation automatic for each line after a `<br />` tag ?

I tried a ugly solution, but it doesn't work because empty paragraph section `<p></p>` doesn't create another line return (in case the user enter 2 line return \n\n).

```
 echo "<div class='infoContent'><p>" . str_replace("<br />", "</p><p>", nl2br($exhib['description'])) . "</p></div>";
```

I can replace `<p></p>` tag  by `<br />` but it seems to be a **very** bad solution...

**EDIT:**
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yv854/)

Thanks

Comment: You can try using `min-height` if you want empty paragraphs to take some space.

Comment: Would you mind showing the output of a couple of paragraphs?

Comment: When you submit the form with php, Try splitting the user defined string at every `\n` and adding four `&nbsp;` after it, then putting the string back together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n\n` usually means a new paragraph (enter). The white space between paragraphs is CSS and is actually default browser styling (`1em` I think?). `\n` is a `<br>` (shift + enter).

So don't use `nl2br()` and do it yourself:

```
$text = '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($text) . '</p>'; // HTML ENCODE!
$text = preg_replace('#\n\n\n*#', '</p><p>', $text); // 2 or more \n
$text = preg_replace('#\n#', '<br />', $text); // all left-over \n
$text = preg_replace('#><#', ">\n<", $text); // if you like </p>\n<p> with a newline between, like I do
```

http://3v4l.org/b0AhL

This is pretty much what Markdown does (and Textile and those): 1 newline = BR (not exactly in Markdown) and 2 newlines = P. I always use simple Markdown for rendering plain text.

Comment: This is the better solution!  You'll just have to account for even more `\n\n`?

Comment: I guess yeah. More than 2 `\n` is also 1 new P. Answer updated.

Comment: It works, Thanks ! To accord to the nl2br doc, the pattern may be `preg_replace("#\n\n\n*|\r\r\r*|\n\r\n\r..."` I don't know why it can be different (explorer ? charset ?). BTW min-height works for empty Paragraph :-)

Comment: Yeah, you should first replace all `(\r\n|\r)` with `\n` and then do all the `\n` replacing. Stupid different line endings.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit your textarea, instead of using CSS to indent only the first line, you can use `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space).

when you submit your text area, I assume you grab it as such:

```
$userText = $_POST['description']
```

Well, before you submit to your database, you could use a simple replace - After you grab the text:

```
$userText = str_replace("\n", "\n &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $userText);
```

Then submit that to the database.  When it comes back, the nl2br will still make the `\n` into a `<br />` and then it won't see the `&nbsp;`, though the HTML will see them as four spaces (equal to an indent).

It's dirty, but simple!

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp